# In form works only first if or both if

Tags: javascript, html, forms, if-statement

i need help, I am new to js.
I try to create a form that shows error when one of the fields or both  is empty
The problem is that  it shows the error when both fields empty or field name is empty, but when i write  name and don't write password its don't show error, that field password is empty.
Sorry for my English it's not my native language.I don't understand why?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function valid()
            {
              
                var fname = document.form.name.value;
                var fpass = document.form.password.value;
                var err = "";
                var ret = true;
    
                if(fname == "" || fname == NULL)
                {
                  err += "Need name.\n";
                } 
    
                if( fpass == "" || fpass == NULL)
                {
                    err += "Need password.!_!";
                }
    
    
                (err != "") ? alert(err) : ret = false;
                  
                return ret;                
            }
        </script>
            <form name="form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="valid()">
                Your Name: <input type="name" name="name"><br><br>
                Your Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                
            </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: fname===null and not fname === NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your ternary operator that *either* shows the alert modal *or* sets the variable `ret` to `false`. This causes the submit to happen, although an error was found. Change the line to

```
if (!(ret=(err==''))) alert(err);
```

and it will work.

```js
function valid() {
  var fname = document.form.name.value;
  var fpass = document.form.password.value;
  var err = "";
  var ret;

  if (fname == "" || fname === null) {
    err += "Need name.\n";
  }

  if (fpass == "" || fpass === null) {
    err += "Need password.!_!";
  }

  if(!(ret=(err==''))) alert(err);

  return ret;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return valid()">
    Your Name: <input type="name" name="name"><br><br> Your Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` conditions are not doing their job as you expect them. See this working example:

```js
function valid() {
  var fname = document.form.name.value;
  var fpass = document.form.password.value;
  var err = "";
  var ret = true;

  if (fname == "" || fname === null) {
    err += "Need name.\n";
  }

  if (fpass == "" || fpass === null) {
    err += "Need password.!_!";
  }


  (err != "") ? alert(err): ret = false;

  return ret;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return valid()">
    Your Name: <input type="name" name="name"><br><br> Your Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```